# Echo output sql JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

How should `echo` output following query?

My tables in MySQL database:

[image]

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT geo.order FROM Store_Information si JOIN Geography AS geo ON geo.id = si.id WHERE si.name LIKE "%' . $find1 . '%"');
```

My try not work:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
   foreach($query as $val) {
      $query_out = $query->row();
      echo $query_out->order . '<br>';
   }
}
else {
    echo '0';
}
```

What do I do?

Comment: Try looking at the example code for [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://ca2.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc).

Comment: What "not work" about it? What do you want to do?

Comment: EXACT DUPLICATE (dupe account?) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805806/combines-two-or-more-select-from-together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `->result()` in your `foreach` loop:

```
// from the docs
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->title;
    echo $row->name;
    echo $row->body;
}
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) guide to better understand how to use codeigniter query results.

basically this code can help:

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
        var_dump($row);
    }
}
```

and don't forget to `$query->free();` your result